# Automatically send email when user enters email address

Tags: javascript, email, sendmail

I´d like to have something that triggers email address to myself as soon as a user enters his email address in my input field. As soon as the email address is entered, an additional class is added to the field. e.g.

No email address entered:

```html
<input class="simpleinput">
```

Email address entered:

```html
<input class="simpleinput emailok">
```

Can you please help?
Thanks much in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking for. Do you want to send an Email or add CSS to the input field?

Comment: what you have tried so far ? Please update your code.

Comment: Do you want to send out email to your email id when ever the user enters a valid emailId in the textbox?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself very well.. I don´t need to add a class. The class is automatically added when user enters email address.. what I would like to have is something that sends an email to myself as soon as the user enters his email address.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `onBlur()` event and then test the regex `/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i` for email. if it matches then add a class.

Or else when the test condition succeeds you can directly add a call to trigger the email.

**JQUERY solution**

```js
$(function(){
    $('.simpleinput').on('blur', function(){
        var valueToTest = $(this).val()
        var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (testEmail.test(valueToTest)){
            alert('ok');
            $(this).addClass('emailOk');
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="simpleinput" type="email">
```

**JS solution**

```js
var ele = document.querySelector('.simpleinput');
ele.addEventListener('blur', function(){

 var valueToTest = this.value
        var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (testEmail.test(valueToTest)){
            alert('ok');
           this.className += emailok;
        }

})
```

```html
<input class="simpleinput" type="email">
```

Comment: `Jquery` is not mentioned in the question tag, So we don't know if the OP is using it or not.

Comment: @Reddy you are right, but this is also a way. If other person chooses to use it. I will update an edit for the javascript version as well. Thanks for reminding, I did not have notice that

Comment: @Reddy added a JS solution

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to add a class when the email was put in the field.

```
var field = document.getElementsByClassName('simpleinput')[0];
field.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    if (field.value.length > 0) {
        field.classList.add('emailok');
    }
});
```

This will add a blur event to you field target and add a class that you want.

Comment: Instead of checking field.value.length > 0 it would be better to use regex(email validator ).What you say?

Comment: Is it just an example.